# What is a fast algorithm for finding the integer square root?

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, integers

> What is a fast algorithm for computing integer square roots on machines that doesn't support floating-point arithmetic?

I'm looking for a fast algorithm for computing the *integer square root* of an integer $N \ge 0$, i.e., the smallest integer $m \ge 0$ such that $m^2 \le N < (m+1)^2$.

The reason is that I'm operating on a virtual machine that doesn't support floating-point arithmetic (real-numbers), so algorithms like Newton's cannot be implemented, right?

The naive solution for finding the square root of $N$ is to check for $m=0,1,\ldots$ whether $m^2 \le N < (m+1)^2$. Is this the best algorithm?

Comment: Apart from the integer version of Newton's algorithm, a binary search is also faster than the naive method (except for very small $N$, but then all methods that aren't insane are fast).

Comment: The optimal solution highly depends
on the amount of RAM and machine commands
available, and whether are you going 
to perform arbitrary precision operations
or just use a fixed-size (which one) integer.

Answer (score 12):

I think the easiest method will Babylonians sqrt method and it works well with machine supporting only integer division.

```
def babylonian(n):
x = n
y = 1
while(x > y):
    x = (x+y)//2
    y = n//x
return x
```

This algorithm runs in approximately $O(\log n)$ time.  More details can be found on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309432/time-complexity-for-babylonian-method).

Answer (score 9):

A fast ($O(\log n)$) way to calculate the integer square root is to use a digit-by-digit algorithm in base2:

$$\text{isqrt(n)} =  \begin{cases}
      n & \text{if $n < 2$} \\
      2\cdot\text{isqrt(n/4)} & \text{if $(2\cdot\text{isqrt(n/4)} + 1)^2 > n$} \\
      2\cdot\text{isqrt(n/4)+1} & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Making sure to calculate $n/4$ using bitshifts, and doing the above iteratively. An example for 16-bit integers can be [found on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Binary_numeral_system_.28base_2.29).

Answer (score 6):

Assuming integer log2 is available, you can get a pretty good starting estimate by rewriting $\sqrt{x}$ like this:
$$\sqrt{x}=x^{\frac{1}{2}}=2^{\frac{\log_{2}{x}}{2}}$$
Integer $\log_{2}$ is often one or two cheap instructions. You just have to refine the result a couple times since everything is floored. This O(1) implementation in C++ finds the square root of every integer $[0, 2^{32}-1]$ in 15 seconds on my PC - about 3.5 ns per iteration.

```
#include <bit>
constexpr uint16_t Sqrt(const uint32_t x) {
    // Avoid divide by zero
    if (x < 2) {
        return static_cast<uint16_t>(x);
    }
    // This code is based on the fact that
    // sqrt(x) == x^1/2 == 2^(log2(x)/2)
    // Unfortunately it's a little more tricky
    // when fast log2 is floored.
    const uint32_t log2x     = std::bit_width(x) - 1;
    const uint32_t log2y     = log2x / 2u;
    uint32_t       y         = 1 << log2y;
    uint32_t       y_squared = 1 << (2u * log2y);
    int32_t        sqr_diff  = x - y_squared;
    // Perform lerp between powers of four
    y += (sqr_diff / 3u) >> log2y;
    // The estimate is probably too low, refine it upward
    y_squared = y * y;
    sqr_diff  = x - y_squared;
    y += sqr_diff / (2 * y);
    // The estimate may be too high. If so, refine it downward
    y_squared = y * y;
    sqr_diff  = x - y_squared;
    if (sqr_diff >= 0) {
        return static_cast<uint16_t>(y);
    }
    y -= (-sqr_diff / (2 * y)) + 1;
    // The estimate may still be 1 too high
    y_squared = y * y;
    sqr_diff  = x - y_squared;
    if (sqr_diff < 0) {
        --y;
    }
    return static_cast<uint16_t>(y);
}
```

The two variable integer divisions in the refinement step aren't cheap, but this was still faster than any of the looping solutions I came up with.

Answer (score 3):

For $1 \leq N \leq 15,$ suggest table lookup. $1 \leq N \leq 3,$ output $1.$ For $4 \leq N \leq 8,$ output $2.$ For $9 \leq N \leq 15,$ output $3.$

Otherwise,
 as far as finding a good starting point, I suppose you can begin with $1,4,16,..., 4^k$ until $4^k \geq N > 4^{k-1}.$ Then let the starting point be $$  x_0 = 2^k  $$

Newton's method with integers and the floor function, but at the very end prevent loops: $$ x_{j+1} = \left\lfloor \frac{x_j^2 + N}{2 x_j} \right\rfloor  $$
As soon as $$ |x_{j+1} - x_j| < 5, $$
switch to your one-at-a-time idea between those endpoints. Otherwise, an infinite loop is possible.

When I programmed this, I let Newton go until consecutive terms were very close together ($<5$). Then I set $m$ to  the smaller one, and increased $m$ by one until the square exceeded $N.$ Then I decreased $m$ by one until the square is no larger than $N.$

Comment: You have found the integer square root - namely $x_j$ - when $x_{j+1} \geqslant x_j$ with $j \geqslant 1$ (that is in case the initial guess $x_0$ was too small, then $x_1 > x_0$ doesn't imply that $x_0$ is the integer square root).

Comment: This is slow because it uses integer division.

Comment: @DanielFischer   I did not put in everything. When I programmed this, I let Newton go until consecutive terms were very close together. Then I set $m$ to  the smaller one, and increased $m$ by one until the square exceeded $N.$ Then I decreased $m$ by one until the square is no larger than $N.$

Comment: I'm just saying that there is a quite simple stopping rule. Iterate until $x_{j+1} \geqslant x_j$, then $x_j$ is it (if $j > 0$).

Comment: @DanielFischer I see what you mean now; that seems better than what I did. At the time, I was dismayed to find an infinite loop I did not understand, until I started putting in cerr commands and so on. The thing I described was my cure, first thing to come to mind.